# Spring ResponseEntity & AJAX error function: can't access response body content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

**SERVER SIDE: Spring Framework**

I have a *Spring Controller* that has a method that returns the type `ResponseEntity<String>`.

For completely good requests I return the following:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(OK_MESSAGE, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
```

But if there's any problem during the execution or Exception catching, I return:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(ERROR_MESSAGE, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Where `ERROR_MESSAGE` contains a customized String for each type of Exception catched.

**CLIENT SIDE: AJAX call**

When that POST method is called and returns *HttpStatus.OK*, AJAX

```
success: function (data, message, xhr)
```

is called and I can easilly access the String `OK_MESSAGE` by accessing `data`.

The **problem** comes that POST method returns *HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST*, AJAX

```
error: function (xhr, status, errMsg)
```

is called but I cannot access the String `ERROR_MESSAGE`sent by the Server, which I need to show the user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @charliebrownie can you please post the code of both ajax and controller?

Comment: Hi! My Spring Controller method returns exactly that, a `ResponseEntity<String>`, where the String is that `ERROR_MESSAGE` variable. The only difference in the AJAX call is that when I get an OK response I can access that String in that `data` variable. Is there a way to access it from the `error` function?

Comment: If you need the code I can do an *edit* or something, but I am wondering if there's a way to access that String I'm passing inside the `ResponseEntity` from the `error` function that I am missing... as there is a way from the AJAX `success` function.

Answer (score 7):

On the controller I return the ResponseEntity in the following way:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>("Enter the full url", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

In the JS I would check the response error string in the following way:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/link',
            data: 'url=/www.stackoverflow.om',
            type: 'GET',

            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert(xhr.status);
            },
            error: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            }
        })
```